# Suggestion to add tags to answer list in user account

Tags: feature-request, tags, answers, profile-page

I would like to see tags in the list of answers under the name of the question. At a minimum, I would find the answer I need much faster.

[image]

Comment: you can use the search bar when you're on your profile(it has your userid) and then enter tags there.